# How create criteria hibernate for query(len(), PATINDEX(),replace)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have hql query:

```
... WHERE len(p.sms.message) - len(replace(p.sms.message,:message1,'')) = 1 AND PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(p.sms.message,:message1,'')) = 0"
```

I need alter the criteria  hibernate like:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("field", field));
```

How do it?

OR i jast need check string by regex `^[^0-9]*[0][^0-9]*$` but I use MSSQL. Can I do it in hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sqlRestriction](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.type.Type))

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(...));
```

Any occurrences of {alias} will be replaced by the table alias.

Comment: I tried it but I have problem. Alias not detected in sql string